# Can I get a housing loan for my father's property

Tags: india, home-loan

I want to apply for a home loan, but the property is registered in my father's name and he is no more. Is it possible? Can anybody help clarify my understanding of home loans?

Comment: Who is probating his will?  When will it be transferred to the inheritor(s)?

Comment: Is any separate registration need?

Comment: In the US, a lawyer would draw up the documents needed by the local Clerk of Court (where all deeds are registered) showing that ownership of the land is to be transferred.  India must have something similar.

Comment: Thanks @RonJohn, I need the Info about in India

Comment: A bank that provides the loan needs a COLLATERAL.

Answer (score 3):

If a property belongs to someone and they die, the property passes on to their *estate*.   Typically it would be your mother (most property held by husband and wife have the right of survivorship).  This should have been handled when their will was read as part of the probate process.

Comment: "*Typically it would be your mother*".  That might not be the case in India.

Comment: @RonJohn Absolutely correct. More strongly, in India it is almost _never_ the case that a husband and wife own a property _jointly_, not even the marital home.

Answer (score 2):

After the death of the property owner, the property passes on to the nominee so just get it checked by an advocate who is the nominee and that person can officially sign all the documents of the respective property